# Programmatically update autofilter before PDF export

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have some code that creates a number of sheets (by copying an existing master sheet), based on an array and then applies an auto filter.

Here is the code I am using to apply the autofilter, as you can see it is configured to apply on the sheet being activated and any cell change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A19").AutoFilter
Range("A19").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("F17").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A19").AutoFilter
Range("A19").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("F17").Value
End Sub
```

My issue is that I then run some further code to save the sheets to a PDF, at which point the sheets have not been activated of changed (so hence the filter not applied)

Below is my save worksheet code:

```
'Code to Save PDF

  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim WksCell As Range

  ' Look at each cell within the range and obtain worksheet names
  For Each WksCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & iHighest).Cells

    ' Attempt to reference the worksheet using this name
    Set wks = Excel.Worksheets(WksCell.Value)
    Set rng = wks.Range("A2:F20")

                        pdfName = wks.Name
                        ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
                        fileSaveName = wks.Name

                        wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                            fileSaveName _
                            , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False



  Next 
End Sub
```

Is there a way to force an update/activation for each of these sheets to trigger the autofilter before the export?

NB. If I click on each sheet manually before the export, it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an iteration of the `.Sheets` collection and call the `.Activate()` method to execute the `Worksheet_Activate()` event (*simulates the clicking on each tab*)

Ie.

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
For Each sh in sheets
    sh.Activate()
Next
```